# Output Clause Explained

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please explain to me the SQL Server output clause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do some examples help? The below all output the result to the client but you can also `OUTPUT INTO` a `@table_variable` (or a standard table under certain conditions)

```
create table T
(
id int identity(1,1),
c char(1)
)

insert into T(c) 
OUTPUT inserted.* /*Output Inserted Rows - shows the ids that were allocated*/
values ('A'),('B'),('C')
```

Returns

```
id          c
----------- ----
1           A
2           B
3           C
```

.

```
UPDATE T
SET c = CHAR(ASCII(c)+1)
 /*Output before and after versions of each row*/
OUTPUT deleted.*, inserted.*
WHERE id IN (2,3)
```

Returns

```
id          c    id          c
----------- ---- ----------- ----
2           B    2           C
3           C    3           D
```

.

```
DELETE 
FROM T
 /*Output the row(s) that were deleted*/
OUTPUT deleted.*
WHERE DATEPART(second, getdate())%id = 0
```

Returns (for example)

```
id          c
----------- ----
1           A
```

### Edit:

In response to comment some examples showing how `OUTPUT`  can be used to insert to a table.

```
CREATE TABLE #T2
(
id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
c CHAR(1)
)

DECLARE @inserted TABLE
(
id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
c CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO #T2(c) 
OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.c 
INTO @inserted
VALUES ('A')
```

If you are on SQL Server 2008 you can [use composable DML](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2009/04/08/Composable-DML.aspx)

```
INSERT INTO @inserted
SELECT I.id, I.c
FROM 
    (
    INSERT INTO #T2(c) 
    OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.c 
    VALUES ('B'),('C')
    ) AS I
WHERE c <> 'C' --Only add rows of interest to @inserted table
```

But you will get an error message if the insert target participates in a PK/FK relationship. [If you encounter this problem you can also use this pattern](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/solutions-to-t-sql-challenge-duplicating-form-entries.aspx).

```
INSERT INTO @inserted
EXEC sp_executesql N'
    INSERT INTO #T2(c) 
    OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.c 
    VALUES (''D''),(''E'') '
```

Comment: I don't see my previous reply, so let me try again....This was a GREAT example and I thank you very much. So can i use the OUTPUT clause to store the value of an ID that is not an IDENTITY column? I'd like to use that value returned to store in a column in another table.

Comment: @robert - I've added some more examples which don't use an `IDENTITY` column and illustrate inserting into a table.

Answer (score 1):

It could be stated as

> How do I find out what rows were deleted, inserted or updated?

You can using some fancy trigger code or a separate SELECT, but the OUTPUT clause make it effortless. The SELECT becomes part of the actual DELETE, INSERT or UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

The `OUTPUT` clause allows you to combine an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` with a `SELECT`.

You can `OUTPUT` a list of fields, and the query will return one row for each row affected by the `INSERT` / `UPDATE`.